# Flutter getx loading data continuously causing UI to be unstable about which data to show

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm trying to load data from my database using Getx in flutter. I have a list of categories containing a list of sub-categories, and each sub-category has a list of products inside of it. The problem is that the UI of the sub-categories page keeps getting confused which list of data to show, since I'm calling data by `category_id`. Something that made my app UI unstable and always changing data.

Here is my code for the sub-categories page:

```
GetBuilder<SubCategoriesController>(builder: (subCategories) {
              Get.find<SubCategoriesController>()
                  .getSubCategories(widget.catId);

              print(Get.find<SubCategoriesController>()
                  .getSubCategories(widget.catId));
                  
              return GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                childAspectRatio: 90 / 100,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                children: List.generate(subCategories.subCategoriesList.length,
                    (index) {
                  return _buildSingleSubCategory(
                      index,
                      SubCategoryModel.fromJson(
                          subCategories.subCategoriesList[index]));
                }),
              );
            })
```

I tried to print the output of

```
Get.find<SubCategoriesController>()
                  .getSubCategories(widget.catId)
```

and I figured out that it keeps running continuously without stopping showing: `Instance of 'Future<void>'`
, and each time it shows data of a specific category, which is pretty weird!

Edit:

```
Future<void> getSubCategories(int cat_id) async {
    Response response = await subCategoriesRepo.getSubCategoriesList(cat_id);
    //print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _subCategoriesList = [];
      _subCategoriesList.addAll(response.body);
      _isLoaded = true;
      update(); // = setState();
    }
  }
```

I found out that the update() function called in here is making the issue, but once I remove it I get no data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are trying to call your `getSubCategories(widget.catId)` from your builder method.

You can try resolving this issue by calling your `getSubCategories(widget.catId)` from initstate instead of in builder method like this:

```js
GetBuilder<SubCategoriesController>(
          initState: (logic) => logic.getSubCategories(widget.catId),
          builder: (subCategories) {
            return GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              mainAxisSpacing: 16,
              crossAxisSpacing: 16,
              childAspectRatio: 90 / 100,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              children: List.generate(subCategories.subCategoriesList.length,
                  (index) {
                return _buildSingleSubCategory(
                    index,
                    SubCategoryModel.fromJson(
                        subCategories.subCategoriesList[index]));
              }),
            );
          },
        )
```